# Eclipse project property/preference page: How to find event of opening preference page in project property window(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to initialize some field value on a preference page at the time of  page get opened 
and i want it for each time page get opened in Project property window(Eclipse).

Comment: Is this a preference page you are creating or a page in an existing plugin?

Comment: I am not using existing preference page ,I am creating a new preference page. Basically i want my preference page to be updated with preference store, i was trying to achieve by property change listener but i m getting org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage` has a `setPreferenceStore` method that you should call in your preference page constructor. The preference store specified often comes from the plugin activator, like this example from the compare plugin preferences:

```
setPreferenceStore(CompareUIPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
```

There is a `getPreferenceStore()` method to call to access this store.

Override `public void setVisible(boolean visible)` if you want to be notified each time the page becomes visible.

Comment: But constructor would only be called once when the page is open first.So i guess some event is required that is fired each time the page is opened & then corresponding fields will be then updated from preference store.

Comment: The page is constructed each time a preference dialog is displayed.

Comment: But in my case a preference page is dependent on another page so constructor will not work as it will only be called after preference dialog is closed and then open again.

Comment: OK, added `setVisible` to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a property change listener.

This may help-

```
public class MyFieldEditorPreferencePage extends PropertyPage {
private Text text;

public void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    IProject project = (IProject) getElement().getAdapter(IProject.class);

    final IPreferenceStore store = Activator
            .getImpaktPreferenceStore(project);

    store.addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(
                org.eclipse.jface.util.PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (text != null && !text.isDisposed())
                text.setText(store.getString("key"));

        }
    });

    setPreferenceStore(store);

}

@Override
protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    initialize();
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    parent.setLayout(layout);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);

    Composite container = new Composite(parent, 0);
    container.setLayoutData(gridData);

    GridLayout containerLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    container.setLayout(containerLayout);
    Label lbl = new Label(container, 0);
    lbl.setText("Locale");

    text = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

    text.setText(getPreferenceStore().getString("impakt.properties.locale"));

    return parent;
}
```

}